# What is the difference between export function and module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I have a Javascript file `utils.js` which contains some utility functions. Here is an example:

```
export function RemoveHTML(Str) {
    return Str.replace(/<[^>]*(?:>|$)/gi,'');
}
```

I can use these functions by importing the `utils.js` file like such:

```
import {RemoveHTML} from '../js/utils.js';
```

I also have a `model.js` file for some data queries like this (pseudo-code for brevity):

```
async function getStuff() {
    await DBConnection.connect();
    return results
}

module.exports = {
  getStuff
}
```

For 'consistency' I thought I'd change `model.js` to just this:

```
export async function getStuff() {
    await DBConnection.connect();
    return results
}
```

If I do that then I get an app crash error stating:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

What is the difference between exporting a function using `export function()` and `module.exports`?

UPDATE:

I am using `Babel` in `Webpack` like below so why would I get an error?:

```
{
      test: /\.js$/,
        include: [ srcPath ],
      exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]  //Preset used for env setup
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: export and import are es6 features not supported by nodejs natively(depending upon the version). either use babel to transpile or maybe set package.json type module or use mjs(again depending upon the nodejs version)

Comment: `export` syntax is new, and not yet supported by NodeJS. `module.exports` is the way NodeJS is providing modules, so that will work natively.

Comment: I am using Babel in my Webpack build. So I shouldn't be getting this error right?

Answer (score 4):

`export function()` is an `ES6` syntax used for exporting while `module.exports` is or `exports` is a special object which is included in every JS file in the `Node.js` application by default. 
 You can also use the ES6 syntax for exporting/importing a module in `Node.js` but for using that you will have to transpile the new `ES6` code to Node.js supported `ES5` format, You can easily do that using [babel](https://babeljs.io/) (which is a tool for transpiling JavaScript).

Comment: I am using Babel in Webpack, but still get the error?

Comment: Do you have a `.babelrc` file?

Comment: No I can't see any `.babelrc` file in my project.

Comment: You need a babel configuration file for babel to work.

Comment: You can go through this small tutorial to setup it https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-node-js-babel-setup#nodejs-with-babel

Comment: I am using `Babel` with `Webpack` so I don't think there is a need for a `.babelrc` file right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212938/discussion-between-rajat-verma-and-volume-one).

Answer (score 2):

@JonasWilms is definitely correct about the point he made. I see you are using commonjs on the server code and es6 on the client-side.

There is no difference between module.export or export. In your project, your server code is using commonjs modules, so you should use module.exports. In your client code, keep on using export (es6) syntax of JavaScript.

But if you want to write your javascript globally with es6, you will have to install some dependencies and configure your babel.

Check out this link https://www.codementor.io/@iykyvic/writing-your-nodejs-apps-using-es6-6dh0edw2o